# How to use Powershell Remote across the internet?

Tags: powershell

I know that Powershell can be used on local network.
But what if the computer that I want to manage is not on the same Lan as mine?
We are each on a seperate LAN and both are behind a firewall.

How can I still manage that PC with powershell remoting ?

PS: Both PCs are running Windows 7 professional

Thanks

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/532613/what-does-it-mean-that-powershell-2-0-will-be-firewall-friendly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BEST course of action is to implement a VPN on the target LAN, and then go through the steps required for enabling PS-Remoting, which is googlable. You don't want to open PS Remoting up to the internet unless you want bad things to happen. A simple vpn can be configured from an old machine with two network interfaces running linux, on up to expensive off the shelf dedicated vpn appliances, depending on how reliable you need it to be. Once the VPN is setup initially, whoever set it up will have to go through the steps to make sure one side can talk to the other, after that you should be all set.