# Is it possible to connect two Pc across the internet through VPN

Tags: vpn, powershell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use Powershell Remote across the internet?](https://superuser.com/questions/532819/how-to-use-powershell-remote-across-the-internet)

My mom and I both have Windows 7 Professional.
We are from different locations connected by Internet.
We are both behind firewalls(A router at home)

I would like to manager her computer by Powershell remote.
How can I reach her PC ?
I suppose I will need a VPN
But I know very little about VPN.
Can I set up a VPN Server on her machine and then connect to it?
I will also need her IP address I guess. I plan to do this by some dynamic IP services.

thanks

Comment: You don't need a VPN to do this. VPN is for providing restricted/limited access, not really for facilitating connections.

Comment: @skypecakes look up "site to site vpn"; http://computer.howstuffworks.com/vpn4.htm

Comment: The VPN is not necessary. So the OP's comment "I suppose I will need a VPN" is not accurate, hence my comment. See Jake223's answer. My point is that VPN is used to provide security for the connection, not to make it easier to connect. 

I've never set up a site-to-site VPN, so I can't say with certainty that it doesn't make connecting easier; but it seems likely to add more complexity.

Comment: @Sirex: BTW if in your experience you have found that site to site vpn does make connecting easier, can you please explain (give an example maybe) or provide a link that proves that? I'd like to understand it better.

Comment: a site to site vpn basically makes it appear like the two networks are linked. It makes connecting easy. setting it up isn't as easy though. Given the original question, a site to site link is total overkill - i just wanted to note that a vpn isn't always just for individual remote users connecting into a network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to set up a VPN and do away with the hassle of using any built-in functionality, [**Hamachi**](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi/) might be one option.  It works from behind firewalls quite happily and would allow you to perform any remote administration of the PC that you would normally be able to do if the two computers were on the same internal network.  It also allows connection to dynamic IP addresses a little easier too, without the need to know it each time.

To enable remote PowerShell access on your mom's computer, you might need to run a few cmdlets from an elevated PowerShell prompt if you have not already done so.  I would have a look at the How-To Geek's article [**here**](http://www.howtogeek.com/117192/how-to-run-powershell-commands-on-remote-computers/) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

You could try forwarding just port 22 on her router to her computer (must know her internal IP address; a static one might be good), then using her public IP address to make an SSH connection to her computer, then just running `ps` once you are at the command line on her computer. Make sure that her password is strong enough that her computer being on the open internet is OK.

A tutorial site for port forwarding: http://portforward.com/
An SSH server for windows: http://mobassh.mobatek.net/
An SSH Client for windows: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/

Comment: you'll want to be using ssh public key authentication.

Comment: If you have dynamic ip on your remote computer,  you can use a ddns service from providers like no-ip.com and configure on your router.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "VPN", I think you mean "VNC".

Take a look at RealVNC and their guide on setting it up. [Link](http://www.realvnc.com/products/open/4.1/winvnc.html).

Comment: No I mean VPN. I think VNC is for desktop sharing. I want commandline connection